# How to create subfolders with IPFS CIDs?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ipfs, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to deploy an NFT. It's a replica from the mfers [contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x79fcdef22feed20eddacbb2587640e45491b757f#readContract). The mfers contract has the token URI referenced as ipfs://QmWiQE65tmpYzcokCheQmng2DCM33DEhjXcPB6PanwpAZo/#

Where # is the token number. Across all tokens, the ipfs hash QmWiQE65tmpYzcokCheQmng2DCM33DEhjXcPB6PanwpAZo is the same. How do you set something like this up in ipfs? Note that ipfs URL returns a json object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you store a folder with 1000 files in it on IPFS?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interacting with IPFS directly, [Mutable File System API](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/file-systems/#mutable-file-system-mfs) abstract away the process of creating directories/subdirectories, treating IPFS as a file system. It isn't how IPFS works, but it is a more intuitive layer on top of IPFS.

If you're uploading via [NFT.storage](https://nft.storage) API or client, you might want to check out an [`uploadDirectory` example](https://gist.github.com/tougerthao/9452b85fcb1f2b2b129c43dd5ecdc885).

See also: https://gist.github.com/tougerthao/9452b85fcb1f2b2b129c43dd5ecdc885